Reporting the recent infestation of new users resorting to gen AI targeting STEM communities
Of late, there has been a surge of new users who venture to various communities and answer at a pretty staggering rate with apparently good looking posts, majority of which would be long and heavy with mathjax formatted equations.
The initial targets were: Cross Validated, Mathematics, Maths Overflow, Physics.
They posed to be jack of all fields: on one hand, they were answering questions of general relativity at Physics, number theory at MO while on other hand, mathematical statistics and probability questions as well as applied statistics problems at CV.
Not that there cannot be a possibility that a bunch of highly intelligent researchers/pro suddenly started posting at Stack Exchange communities; but it was all too good to be true.
Of late, they started venturing at Quantitative Finance, Signal Processing, Theoretical Computer Science, Artificial Intelligence, Cryptography.
What I have been able to observe, those users follow the same rule book:

they post at a staggering rate, at least two answers in a community they choose for a day and it could be more than one community. Earlier the time difference used to be four to five minutes but it has increased quite a bit now;

the posts are pretty neat and sleak and are heavy with mathjax and most would be long;

they hardly comment to any question to the post and even if they do, for all intent and purpose, they are not helpful;

once they get banned in one or two communities, they slowly stop posting from that account and suddenly another new user with the same modus operandi pops up.


The traits can change and they are definitely evolving their behaviors. For ordinary users, it would be pretty hard to detect these are apparently gen ai generated or at best mixed with human language.
Prominent users are one, one whose account has been deleted, three, four, five, according to my observation and subsequent banning or deletion of their accounts after being reported and flagged in any one of the communities they were involved.
In fact, some have evaded earlier bans and have been banned thus. And some are about to be banned.
In any case, there could be others lurking in some other sites beyond our vigil eyes.
So what is the point of this post? Another debate on AI generated contents?
No, I am not here for that -- there has been already many by more experienced fellow community members (although, I personally am somewhat hostile to any form of AI materials, and my opinion is summed up here in The h Bar by another fellow user).
As I noted, the latest developed gen AI are way more efficient in evading any ordinary AI detectors (not that they were very reliable earlier either) and are producing rather coherent, kinda meaningful posts for them to be detected compared to, say, gibberish contents by ChatGPT two years ago (more like Mathgen becoming less nonsensical). They are accruing many upvotes, answers are getting accepted and bounty awarded (although some are still really bad answers, as in cs theory).
This post is for the general cognizance of this phenomenon for the communities; I have personally observed for days, alerted moderators, flagged those suspicious posts as well as informed other fellow users across communities, who are also sieving through these posts and flagging them (see the recent Ten Fold and The h Bar conversations; a clap of appreciation for those users and moderators).
The minuscule thing to be done is to at least acknowledge the usage of gen ai in their posts (so far, only one did), otherwise it's a case of plagiarism.
While I am not aware of whether there is any form of communication between different communities' moderators, I feel  it would be good if when such user is banned in one community for plagiarism, the moderators of the other communities, where this user is logged in, should be alerted so as to nip these nefarious activities at the bud.
I am not sure what should be the course of action now that gen ai are getting improved day after day, and mere imposing a ban would stop these bunch of users anytime soon.
However, if someone notices rather long, sleek posts from a new user, please spend a few minutes to check their overall behaviors (unless they change these traits altogether) -- whether they comment or not etc and whether they are simultaneously posting diversified topics of different fields within a short span of time -- anything that tantamounts to too good to be true feeling, raise flags for moderators' attention.
Note, I do know using gen ai is not a new thing here. What is different is the similar modus operandi by definitely not isolated users to target these STEM communities -- it is not sporadic. I am reporting this here and not re igniting the old debate again, as has been emphasized above.

This is not a recent occurrence, it has been happening for months (years, on some sites). Another post for raising awareness is not necessary. There is already a process in place for handling such users. Flag them for moderator attention, explain your concerns, downvote if and where possible, and then move on.

Yes @Nij. I agree with you. That's what I said is the best course of action. I am rather reporting the sudden surge of all these similar targets in recent weeks.

It should be noted that not all SE sites ban AI generated content, but all require proper attribution of sources, which however always was and always will be difficult to fact-check. And there is growing mistrust between users, anyone could be a cheater using AI and publishing under its own name, even high rep users. Some of the benefits of the new time.

@security_paranoid actually this is a perfect example of a good discussion. There's no concrete request for a feature, but rather asking for ideas and help from SE staff. Kind of a "Call for action" post.

From one of the linked users: "This account is temporarily suspended for ban evasion. The suspension period ends on Dec 24, 2025 at 9:46." - ??? It's not as if the account will ever stop being a ban evasion account.

@KarlKnechtel I guess the mods just followed the defined process for suspensions etc.

@KarlKnechtel Mods can’t suspend for more than 1 year
